# Joining two tables MySQL is slow even with indexing

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables:

The first one `table1` is created on the fly (as the user submits data from a web server) and is usually ~50K rows. The second table is a lookup table `table2` and has ~10Mil rows.

I'm trying to join both tables on four columns as follows:

```
SELECT t.id FROM table1 t 
JOIN table2 m
ON (t.name = m.name AND t.pos = m.pos AND t.ref = m.ref AND t.alt = m.alt);
```

I've indexed columns `name` (VARCHAR), `pos` (INT), `ref` (CHAR) and `alt` (CHAR) in `table2`, but the query still takes way too long to complete.

Any pointers on what could be going wrong here?

Thanks

---

Output of `EXPLAIN`:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t1  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    49329   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  t2  NULL    ref table2_name,table2_pos,table2_ref,table2_alt    table2_name 32  my_db.t1.NAME   2488    0.00    Using index condition; Using where
```

Comment: Why didnt you use id's?

Comment: @by0, what is the engines of those tables?

Comment: Because I'm joining based on what the user submits on the webserver, if that makes sense. The engine is InnoDB

Comment: Have you indexed the table you create on the fly?

Comment: @HLGEM I've also tried that it didn't help.

Comment: How many records are you returning?

Comment: @HLGEM I'm expecting ~1-2K records

Comment: If you're creating `table1` on the fly, why not use a temporary table, which will live in memory for the session.  Do you need it for more than one session?  That will surely increase speed, but then the question comes to whether the allocated memory on the system is available to support the temporary table and 4+ indexes on ~10 million rows.

Comment: When I'm troubleshooting slow queries one of the first things I look at this the results of "explain".  Have you tried that already?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: did you make 4 separate indices, or one compound index?  I don't think the 4 single indices will help here - correct me someone if i am wrong.

Comment: Update your question with the output of EXPLAIN SELECT t.id FROM table1 t 
JOIN table2 m
ON (t.name = m.name AND t.pos = m.pos AND t.ref = m.ref AND t.alt = m.alt);

Comment: @dashnick I made four separate indicies. @jesse-weigert I've updated the question to include the `EXPLAIN` output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a compound index on `name, pos, ref, alt`

like

```
INDEX theIndex (name,pos,ref, alt)
```

Also, 4 single indices will help a little bit - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html - but not as much as a compound index.

Comment: Just in case the questioner needs it, you might want to include the syntax for creating the index.

Comment: Thank you! Spent all day trying to figure this out! Do I still need to create individual indices if I wan't to query by one or two of the columns? Or will the compound index suffice for that?

Comment: Sure thing - if you want to only query by some prefix of these columns - say name, or name pos, or name pos ref, then you don't need individual indices.  But if you need pos by itself, for example, then you'll need a separate index for that.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to try here:

1. The first is the easiest -- change the order of your join clause to move the varchar column to the end.

> SELECT t.id FROM table1 t  JOIN table2 m ON (t.pos = m.pos AND t.ref =
>   m.ref AND t.alt = m.alt AND t.name = m.name);

2. This is a little more work, but add a new computed column that generates a numeric hash based on the 4 columns.  Remove the indexes on pos, ref, alt and name and add a new index to the the hash column.  Then include the hash column in your join clause.

> SELECT t.id FROM table1 t  JOIN table2 m ON (t.hash = m.hash AND t.pos = m.pos AND t.ref =
>   m.ref AND t.alt = m.alt AND t.name = m.name);

Edit: Without looking at your database and the query execution plan, it's hard to troubleshoot this, but my guess is that MySQL is having a hard time joining on the VARCHAR column.  Can you update your question with the results of

> EXPLAIN SELECT t.id FROM table1 t JOIN table2 m ON (t.name = m.name
>   AND t.pos = m.pos AND t.ref = m.ref AND t.alt = m.alt)

Answer (score 0):

Index for any tables:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    'ALTER TABLE ', 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    ' ', 
    'ADD ', 
    IF(
      NON_UNIQUE = 1, 
      CASE UPPER(INDEX_TYPE) WHEN 'FULLTEXT' THEN 'FULLTEXT INDEX' WHEN 'SPATIAL' THEN 'SPATIAL INDEX' ELSE CONCAT(
        'INDEX ', INDEX_NAME, ' USING ', INDEX_TYPE
      ) END, 
      IF(
        UPPER(INDEX_NAME) = 'PRIMARY', 
        CONCAT(
          'PRIMARY KEY USING ', INDEX_TYPE
        ), 
        CONCAT(
          'UNIQUE INDEX ', INDEX_NAME, ' USING ', 
          INDEX_TYPE
        )
      )
    ), 
    '(', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      DISTINCT CONCAT('', COLUMN_NAME, '') 
      ORDER BY 
        SEQ_IN_INDEX ASC SEPARATOR ', '
    ), 
    ');'
  ) AS 'Show_Add_Indexes' 
FROM 
  information_schema.STATISTICS 
WHERE 
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database' 
  and TABLE_NAME = 'your_table';
-- GROUP BY 
--   TABLE_NAME, 
--   INDEX_NAME 
-- ORDER BY 
--   TABLE_NAME ASC, 
--   INDEX_NAME ASC;
```